# How can I pass different s3 bucket for terraform backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am saving terraform state to s3 bucket by this doc: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html

But it mentioned that I can't use variables `A backend block cannot refer to named values (like input variables, locals, or data source attributes).`

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need to run `terraform` in different AWS account and regions. My s3 bucket name includes accountId and region. How can I make it work without manually update the configuration file?

Comment: You need to create some kind of wrapper script that configures terraform to use different backends: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html#partial-configuration - alternatively [terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) should be able to do these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

I think of using Ansible for this scenario. This may not be the most efficient way to do it or the correct use of Ansible but you can make use of Jinja2 templating. So you can create a Jinja2 template file like below.

terraform.tf.j2

```
 terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "{{ aws-account-name/id }}-{{ aws-region }}-terraform"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Then when you create the infrastucture, you can feed necessary values to `terraform.tf.j2` file and create `terraform.tf` file dynamically.